# wp_trash_post not firing

Tags: trash

I want to call a function when a post is placed into the trash. I want to do something more complicated than the following, but have simplified to what's below just to see if it'll work and it doesn't.

```
function gna_my_function() {
    echo 'trashed ';
}
add_action('wp_trash_post', 'gna_my_function');
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your function trying to do? How are you sure it's not firing?

Comment: Because it wasn't echoing. But the answer below describes why that was the case. So it must have been a bug in something else I had written. I should hopefully be able to figure it out now though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two hooks you should be considering-- [`wp_trash_post`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/post.php#L2407) and [`trashed_post`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/post.php#L2417). Based on your statement that you want this to work "when a post is placed into the trash" I'd suggest the latter is the better hook, since it runs *after* the post is successfully placed in the trash.

I hate to suggest this as an answer but I do think it explains why your function does not appear to output anything. When WordPress saves a post a request is sent to the server, the request is processed, and then the browser is redirected back to the originating page. That means that you cannot always see dumped/`echo`ed output without killing the script. I believe the following should make your apparently debugging function do what you expect it to, provided that you have "trash" enabled.

```
function gna_my_function() {
    echo 'trashed '; die;
}
add_action('wp_trash_post', 'gna_my_function');
```

Comment: that does end up printing stuff to the screen. it kills everything else, but it does allow me to double check what's happening. thx

Comment: Right. Being able to see the debugging output is the the entire point. You can't leave it that way. You could send that output to the log file but I typically don't. It rarely seems worth the effort.

Comment: You can also send the debug info per HTTP-Header and use your browsers debugger to watch this.